# Xamarin Forms (Android) StartForegroundService not work (App crash)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-service

The xamarin forms should be started with **StartForegroundService** service on **Android 8.0** versions as it is known for doing a bacgroudservice.

But my service does not start and my application is crashing.

My Code :

```
 var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, new ServiceScreen().Class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            StartForegroundService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            StartService(intent);
        }
```

My ServiceScreen.cs

```
 public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        try
        {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionScreenOn);
            filter.AddAction(Intent.ActionScreenOff);
            BroadcastReceiver broadcast = new receiverScreen();
            RegisterReceiver(broadcast, filter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("Hata", e.ToString());
        }
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        var broadcastIntent = new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(RestarterBroadcastReceiver));
        SendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

My receiverScreen.cs

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class receiverScreen : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        if (intent.Action.Equals(Intent.ActionScreenOn))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "On Screen", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Log.Debug(TAG, "-------------- on !");
        }
        else if (intent.Action.Equals(Intent.ActionScreenOff))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Off Screen", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Log.Debug(TAG, "-------------- off !");
        }
    }
}
```

My App Output

> 12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002): Service md5108cbe39ce2243540ccf5f375034c930.ServiceScreen has leaked IntentReceiver com.xxx.xxx.receiverScreen@14a30de that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service md5108cbe39ce2243540ccf5f375034c930.ServiceScreen has leaked IntentReceiver com.xxx.xxx.receiverScreen@14a30de that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1351)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1132)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1421)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1394)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1382)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:609)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at md5108cbe39ce2243540ccf5f375034c930.ServiceScreen.n_onStartCommand(Native Method)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at md5108cbe39ce2243540ccf5f375034c930.ServiceScreen.onStartCommand(ServiceScreen.java:39)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3474)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   12-08 10:58:09.089 E/ActivityThread(13002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   12-08 10:58:09.466 I/zygote  (13002): Thread[3,tid=13008,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa6b4ec00,peer=0x12d41350,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
>   12-08 10:58:09.466 I/zygote  (13002): 
>   12-08 10:58:09.505 I/zygote  (13002): Wrote stack traces to '[tombstoned]'
>   12-08 10:58:10.378 D/AndroidRuntime(13002): Shutting down VM
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002): Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 13002
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   12-08 10:58:10.381 E/AndroidRuntime(13002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>   Unhandled Exception:

Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException:

Comment: If [this is the code you're running](https://codeshare.io/UbKVU), and that's still the stack trace you get, then it seems like something in your `startForeground()` method is throwing an Exception, but you're essentially ignoring it. Either look elsewhere in your logs for the `Log.Debug("Error", e.ToString());` log, or remove that `try-catch` so that Exception is what crashes it, then that'll be the main Exception in your stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st. You can creating a Service instance just to obtain the Java class:

```
new ServiceScreen().Class
```

Create your intent using the overload that accepts a C# type or obtain the Java class via `Java.Lang.Class.FromType`

Example:

```
var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(ServiceScreen));
var intent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ServiceScreen));
```

> Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()

2nd. You are calling `StartForegroundService` but not calling `StartForeground` within the creation of the Service. This has to be done within a set amount of time otherwise the OS will terminate the Service.

```
var notification = ForegroundNotification("Some Title", "Some User notification");
StartForeground(99, notification);
```

Note: You can do this within the Service's `OnCreate()` override.

Comment: Not work :/
I searched everywhere, but couldn't find a clear source, can you help me please?

one source, one way ...

Comment: @UfukŞahin Did you add the call to `StartForeground` within your Service as my answer states?

Comment: @UfukŞahin The error you posted states that you are not calling StartForeground after calling StartForegroundService : `Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground()`

Comment: Thanks for your support, you are a great man. my all service code https://codeshare.io/UbKVU